# Access violation on 2nd iteration of for loop when accessing a 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, access-violation

I have an assignment in C where the user has to populate a 2D `grades[3][3]` array. Then a function is called that returns a pointer to `main()` with the address of the max element in that array.

So, I've defined a `int *get_max()` function with the following body:

```
int *get_max(float *gradesPtr)
{
    int i, j, *max_addr = &i; //variable initialization
    float max = *gradesPtr, curr_element; //max gets the value of the 1st element in the array to not be empty

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            curr_element = *(gradesPtr + i*3 + j); //(pointer + i*columns + j) formula used here
            if (curr_element > max)
            {
                max = curr_element; //get max element
                *max_addr = gradesPtr + i*3 + j; //get address of max element
            }
        }
    }

    return max_addr; //return "max_addr" to main
}
```

It's called from `main()` like this:

```
int *max_element = get_max((float *)grades);
```

The code seems correct, since I can verify through the Watch menu in Visual Studio that it runs fine on the 1st iteration, and that the variables have the correct values. On the 2nd iteration, though, instead of continuing normally, it throws an access violation error on the `curr_element = *(gradesPtr + i*3 + j);` line.

After debugging it for a bit, it seems that no matter how I pass the array to the function (using a pointer to the array or passing the whole array itself) and no matter how I save the address of the max element to `*max_addr` (either by using the (pointer + i*columns + j) formula or by `&grades[i][j]`), the `get_max()` function sees the array as a **1D array instead of a 2D one**, thus throwing the access violation error. Searching here provided some good-looking solutions, but they were not what I wanted.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: `max_element` is a [simple] `int`, but `get_max` returns `int *` (a pointer). So, how does this compile?

Comment: @CraigEstey Oops, my bad. `max_element` is initialized at the beginning of the original file and I forgot to put the asterisk here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `grades` is a two-dimensional array, you should define the parameter and return value appropriately

```
float *get_max(float gradesPtr[3][3])
```

Now there's no need anymore to do pointer arithmetic and you may simply say

```
float *get_max(float grades[3][3])
{
    int i, j;
    float *max_addr = &grades[0][0]; //variable initialization
    float max = *max_addr;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            float curr_element = grades[i][j];
            if (curr_element > max)
            {
                max = curr_element; //get max element
                max_addr = &grades[i][j]; //get address of max element
            }
        }
    }

    return max_addr; //return "max_addr" to main
}
```

Comment: So it seems that the issue was probably in the way I initialized the variables. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

In `get_max`, you do:

```
int i, *max_addr = &i;
```

Thus, `max_addr` is pointing [initially] to the function scoped variable `i`.

If the `if (curr_element > max)` is *never* true, `max_addr` will never be *updated*. The function will return a `max_addr` that points to the stack.

This is UB (undefined behavior) because `i` goes out of scope.

The `if` will fail to be true *if* the first element of the array (e.g. `gradesPtr[0]` aka `grades[0][0]`) is the maximum.

And, inside the `if`, you're changing what `max_addr` points to rather than updating `max_addr`.

So, you want to change (which won't compile):

```
*max_addr = gradesPtr + i * 3 + j;
```

Into:

```
max_addr = gradesPtr + i * 3 + j
```

`max_addr` is a `float *` but the return value of the function is `int *`. So, I'm not sure how this compiles.

Instead of:

```
int *max_addr = &i;
```

You want:

```
float *max_addr = gradesPtr;
```

And, you want to change the return value to `float *`

---

Here's the refactored code:

```
float *
get_max(float *gradesPtr)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    float *max_addr = gradesPtr;
    // max gets the value of the 1st element in the array to not be empty
    float max = *gradesPtr;
    float curr_element;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            // (pointer + i*columns + j) formula used here
            curr_element = *(gradesPtr + i * 3 + j);

            // get max element and address of max element
            if (curr_element > max) {
                max = curr_element;
                max_addr = gradesPtr + i * 3 + j;
            }
        }
    }

    return max_addr;
}
```

---

Since you're using a 1D pointer in the function *and* are returning a *pointer* we can treat the array as 1D:

```
float *
get_max(float *gradesPtr)
{
    float *max_addr = gradesPtr;
    float max_val = *max_addr;
    float *end_ptr = gradesPtr + (3 * 3);
    float *cur_ptr;

    for (cur_ptr = gradesPtr;  cur_ptr < end_ptr;  ++cur_ptr) {
        if (*cur_ptr > max_val) {
            max_val = *cur_ptr;
            max_addr = cur_ptr;
        }
    }

    return max_addr;
}
```